# Send Video Stream to HoloLens

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, video-streaming, hololens

Is there a way to send video to HoloLens. There seems to many options to transmit the video captured by HoloLens to PC, but is there a way around?
I want to send the data captured by my camera (stereo camera) to HoloLens and display it there in real time. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: We came up with something working using uwp video streaming (basic .net streaming) and MovieTexture. It works but is way too slow to be used.

Comment: @Everts could you please explain a little more about your implementation, it may give me some idea on how to proceed or maybe I could figure something out to speed it up.

Comment: I was not the coder so those are just ideas. The UWP code is done in VS, so you cannot debug it in editor as it uses code that Unity does not recognize. This is the basic opening of the socket, getting the data and turning into byte array so you can forward to MovieTexture. MT is fairly slow. The other way is the Unity way as shown on their docs, you make WWW call in a coroutine, wait for the result and display then start a new call infinitely. Quite memory consuming and even slower but if you do not require a high frequency, this could be a quick solution.

Comment: Thanks for the info.

Comment: movie texture is in slow performance. Unity 5.6(still in beta) provides a new movie player with improved performance. Or you can buy one from asset store.